# Como inserir dados na string em C++ usando a IDE Geany?

Tags: c++, funções, dev-c++, library, geany

Eu estou estudando tipos de String em C. A mais comum era `gets()` porém ela foi descontinuada em razão de "buffer overflow". Eu gostaria de saber qual a função equivalente na IDE Geany ao `gets()`. Eu já tentei `gets_s()` e também não funciona. Esse código abaixo sempre dá problema ao compilar... Ele disse que 'gets' não foi declarado no escopo e sugere `fgets()`, porém a função também não funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

char name[50];

printf("Insira um nome: ");
gets(name);

printf("O nome inserido foi: %s \n", name);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Utilizar a biblioteca stdio significa que você está tentando fazer algo em c, porém como sua pergunta refere-se à c++, usarei ela para realizar esse processo de obtenção do conjunto de caracteres do usuário.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void){
char* name = new char[50];//tamanho do array para armazenar o nome
std::cout << "Digite um nome" << std::endl;//imprime o requerimento na tela
std::cin >> name;//obtém o conteúdo digitado no prompt
std::cout ​<< "O nome inserido foi " << name << std::endl; //imprime na tela
delete name;
}
```

Os "std::" no código indica que estou utilizando um namespace proveniente da biblioteca iostream, porém você pode remover os std das linhas e incluir no topo do programa using namespace std

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;/*isso não causa problema na maioria dos casos, porém não é 
recomendado fazer isso*/
int main(void){
char* name = new char[50];//tamanho do array para armazenar o nome
cout << "Digite um nome" << endl;//imprime o requerimento na tela
cin >> name;//obtém o conteúdo digitado no prompt
cout ​<< "O nome inserido foi " << name << endl; //imprime na tela
delete name;
}
```

O "char*" representa um ponteiro do tipo char(caractere) o "new char[50]" aloca para esse ponteiro 50 espaços, que foi o tamanho que você colocou

O delete serve para de-alocar o ponteiro, pois ele não é excluído automaticamente como as declarações de arrays comuns

```
int nums[5]; /* array de 5 espaços que será excluído ao final do programa, forma 
mais comum e intuitiva/*
int* nums_a = new int[5]; /*mesma quantidade de espaços, porém devidamente alocados
e isso evita perda de memória quando o programa entra em stacks*/
delete nums_a; //de-aloca nums_a
```

se alguém notar algo de errado na minha resposta, fale o quanto antes que eu edito o quanto antes

Comment: Por que não faz um código C++ por inteiro? E um código moderno como se recomenda fazer? Essa resposta ensina a fazer errado.